# Skip Code When Looping Through List If Individual Worksheet Doesn't Exist

Tags: excel, vba

I have tried a bunch of different things I have seen here and on other forums but cannot get my code to work.

**I want the code to simply skip passed trying to copy data from the "Managers" tab if there is no managers tab in that file. I then need it to close the file and move onto the next in the list.**

The master file has 2 tabs where i want all of the data from the relevant tabs copied onto. Each individual file also has the same tabs, but only with their places data.

If I use an "On Error GoTo Skip" then it works if I only select the workbook which doesn't have the 2nd tab, but when selecting the full list (approx. 42) I get a runtime error 9.
I believe I need to incorporate a check to confirm if the worksheet exists likely using an If Else but haven't been able to get that to work.

Here is the code:

```
Sub Merge()

     'Facilitates selecting the applicable files to be consolidated.
     Dim TargetFiles As FileDialog
     'Allows the macro to loop through the files once they have been selected.
     Dim FileIdx As Long
     'Sets variables so that each file can be accessed once selected.
     Dim Databook As Workbook

'Speeds up the macro.
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.Calculation = xlManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

'Opens up File Explorer so that all relevant files can be selected.
Set TargetFiles = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)

     With TargetFiles
     .AllowMultiSelect = True
     .Title = "Select all files."
     .ButtonName = ""
     .Filters.Clear
     .Filters.Add ".xls* files", "*.xls*"
     .Show
     End With

'Loop through all files.
For FileIdx = 1 To TargetFiles.SelectedItems.Count
'Sets the workbook so that we can loop through.
Set Databook = Workbooks.Open(TargetFiles.SelectedItems(FileIdx))

     'Copies the relevant data from the specified section.
     Databook.Worksheets("Staff").Unprotect
     Databook.Worksheets("Staff").AutoFilterMode = False
     Databook.Worksheets("Staff").Range("A3:O1000").Copy
      
     'Pastes it into the relevant area in the Database file.
     Workbooks("Master Review - Test File").Sheets("Staff").Activate
     'Macro seems to paste over the top rather than at the bottom if you don't activate A1 first.
     Range("A1").Activate
     Range("A100000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Activate
     'Increase the 100000 above if your data is more than 100000 rows.
     Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
     :=False, Transpose:=False

          'Copies the relevant data from the specified section.
          Databook.Worksheets("Managers").Unprotect
          Databook.Worksheets("Managers").AutoFilterMode = False
          Databook.Worksheets("Managers").Range("A3:P5000").Copy

          'Pastes it into the relevant area in the Database file.
          Workbooks("Master Review - Test File").Sheets("Managers").Activate
          'Macro seems to paste over the top rather than at the bottom if you don't activate A1 first.
          Range("A1").Activate
          Range("A100000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Activate
          'Increase the 100000 above if your data is more than 100000 rows.
          Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
          :=False, Transpose:=False

'Closes the current workbook and moves onto the next one which has been selected
Databook.Close False

'Clears the clipboard at the end of each workbook being copied.
Application.CutCopyMode = False

Next

'Reset back to normal.
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
Application.AskToUpdateLinks = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the sheets and select  the ones you want to copy with `If ws.name =`

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Merge()

    'Facilitates selecting the applicable files to be consolidated.
    Dim TargetFiles As FileDialog
    'Allows the macro to loop through the files once they have been selected.
    Dim FileIdx As Long
    'Sets variables so that each file can be accessed once selected.
    Dim Databook As Workbook

    'Speeds up the macro.
    With Application
        .DisplayAlerts = False
        .Calculation = xlManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .DisplayStatusBar = False
        .AskToUpdateLinks = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    'Opens up File Explorer so that all relevant files can be selected.
    Set TargetFiles = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)

    With TargetFiles
        .AllowMultiSelect = True
        .Title = "Select all files."
        .ButtonName = ""
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add ".xls* files", "*.xls*"
        .Show
    End With

    'Loop through all files.
    Dim ws As Worksheet, wb As Workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks("Master Review - Test File")

    For FileIdx = 1 To TargetFiles.SelectedItems.Count
        'Sets the workbook so that we can loop through.
        Set Databook = Workbooks.Open(TargetFiles.SelectedItems(FileIdx))
        For Each ws In Databook.Sheets
            If ws.Name = "Staff" Then

                'Copies the relevant data from the specified section.
                ws.Unprotect
                ws.AutoFilterMode = False
                ws.Range("A3:O1000").Copy
                 
                'Pastes it into the relevant area in the Database file.
                wb.Sheets("Staff").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial _
                        Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
                        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

            ElseIf ws.Name = "Managers" Then
    
                'Copies the relevant data from the specified section.
                 ws.Unprotect
                 ws.AutoFilterMode = False
                 ws.Range("A3:P5000").Copy
        
                 'Pastes it into the relevant area in the Database file.
                 wb.Sheets("Managers").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial _
                          Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
                          SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
            End If
        Next
       'Closes the current workbook and moves onto the next one which has been selected
        Databook.Close False
        'Clears the clipboard at the end of each workbook being copied.
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Next

    'Reset back to normal.
    With Application
        .DisplayAlerts = True
        .Calculation = xlAutomatic
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .DisplayStatusBar = True
        .AskToUpdateLinks = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With

End Sub
```